# Launching Windows Form on IIS - any workaround?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, iis

I faced problem with IIS web application. There is some RTF processing needed on server side and this can be done with windows control. This control requires to be created and shown in order to perform operations (RTF stuff).

I would like to expose web-service from IIS that could launch windows form on Windows Server (the one that is hosting IIS), perform some work and return data to web-service. Problem is that IIS does not allow to launch windows forms.

Requirement is to host whole app on IIS. Windows Service installed separately is not an option here. I tried deploying WCF service on IIS that that didn't worked too.

Comment: Unless you give full trust to your .NET app, you will hardly be able to do this. And giving full trust to one application compromises the entire server.

Comment: The situation you've described sounds like someone didn't do their homework and because of this you're going to have to come up with a really hacky solution. The real solution would be whatever RTF (rich text format I assume?) processing that needs to be done should be ported to a library.

Comment: Are you certain you need to actually show the control? This MSDN topic, [How to: Convert RTF to Plain Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc488002.aspx), indicates that you can do at least *some* RTF processing with the `RichTextBox` control without actually having to display the control.

Comment: Yes, this is very specific situation. This is custom RTF control that does conversion. No option to switch to other. Thank you for your input. It looks like we went wrong way. Your posts confirmed this. Having even windows service appeared to be a problem with certain deployment scenarios we can face.